# Unable to select items from the Spinner in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-spinner

I am new to Android Studio, so I don't know much about the functions. I am using a spinner which allows me to choose from different languages.

In my MainActivity class, I have the following code:

```js
String lang="eng";
dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                Object language = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                TextView L = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinLang);

                //for deciding tessdata file
                if(language.toString().equals("Bengali"))
                    lang="ben";
                if(language.toString().equals("English"))
                    lang="eng";
                if(language.toString().equals("Gujarati"))
                    lang="guj";
                if(language.toString().equals("Hindi"))
                    lang="hin";
                if(language.toString().equals("Kannada"))
                    lang="kan";
                if(language.toString().equals("Tamil"))
                    lang="tam";
                L.setText("You selected " + language + " and " + lang);
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

My text view shows the display depending on what language I choose from the spinner. However, I believe the change in variable `<lang>` is limited to only this method.

Outside this method, when I am working with `<lang>`, it gives the result for `<lang="eng">` all of the time.

How can I make the change in `<lang>` outside this method? Thanks in advance.